# Elastic Search - Sort By Doc Type

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic search index with 2 different doc types: `'a'` and `'b'`. I would like to sort my results by type and give preference to `type='b'` (even if it has a low score). I had been consuming the results of the search below at the client end and sorting them but I've realized that this approach does not work well since I am only inspecting the first 10 results which often does not contain any b's. Increasing the return results is not ideal. I'd like to get the elastic search to do the work.

`http://<server>:9200/my_index/_search?q=london`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to play with [`function_score`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) and, depending on how you already score your documents, [test some `weight` values, `boost_mode`s and `score_mode`s](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_using_function_score) for each type. For example:

```
GET /some_index/a,b/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        # your query here
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "type": {
              "value": "b"
            }
          },
          "weight": 3
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "type": {
              "value": "a"
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "first",
      "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Andrei, this works perfectly. This was my first experience with stack overflow and I'm amazed by the generosity of people. Restores my faith in human kind!

Answer (score -1):

Its working for me.you will execute below commands at command Prompt.

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/index_v1,index_v2/_search?pretty -d @boost.json
```

boost.json
{

```
"indices_boost" : {
    "index_v2" : 1.4,
    "index_v1" : 1.3

}
```

}

Comment: What you are saying is boosting per index, the author needs boosting per type.

Comment: Thanks for responding BasK. Andrei is correct, I needed to sort via doc type in the same index. His example works a treat. Thanks both very much.